# What's alternative to BDE engine that will work with Paradox Table?

Tags: delphi, installation, bde, paradox

I am working with Paradox table using BDE engine. Lately, we are simply running into all kinds of problem trying to install BDE engine - Out of space, Error Copying BLW32.dll file, on and on. However, if you keep trying it eventually installs.

I am seriously thinking about moving away from BDE Engine all together. So, I would like to know what is out there that will work with Paradox table.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but when I ran into a similar issue a few years back, I solved it by converting the whole thing to a Firebird database. ;)

Comment: Paradox was a great idea in 1998. Not a great idea anymore.  Besides Firebird, you may also want to consider SqLite, PostGres, and MySql.

Comment: @WarrenP - More like in 1988! I think the only time I used in was in 1990.

Comment: I didn't learn to embrace SQL databases until about 2008. I'm a late bloomer.

Comment: What Delphi version are you using now?

Comment: ...or NexusDB - it has free version for single-user applications. While i personalyl would consider Firebird more reliable, deployment of single EXE is a bit easier (and embedding OBJs of SQLite into EXE is not always smooth). About reliabiltiy against data files corruption... If Paradox is enought for you, then NexusDB would probably be not worse.

Comment: @JanDoggen I am using RAD Studio XE Version 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all of you have suggested and commented, I totally agree that install for BDE Engine on latest windows is very very buggy. However, I believe that its installation is the one that seems to be having problem not the BDE Engine itself.

As suggested by other question in Stackoverflow, I came to a conclusion that I should be able to take the extracted files from common\bde folder and link them to my software install. So, that whenever I install my software, BDE Engine files also get transferred into its folder on C drive. That it does. Also, I have created the registry file to update the registry accordingly for the BDE. It is mainly located in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Borland. To create the registry file, just right click on the folder and choose "Export" option. I shellexecute the registry file as part of the installation process.

It all works without any problem. Now, I don't have to deal with all these errors. My software is up and running. For now this is a quick fix but definitely going to get rid of it in the next revision.

Comment: this is a quick patch, not a fix.BDE is not the only problem, paradox is problematic too. It easily  gets corrupted as tables grow, if they reside on a network share etc etc... A mininal fix would be moving to SQLite. A real fix would be to move to a real database, like PostgreSQL, MySQL etc.

Comment: Eventually that's what I ended up doing especially when I migrated the software to Linux Environment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326548/en-us

It's about the Jet OLE-DB provider that, acording to this paper, is able to open Paradox 5 files. I'm not sure what Paradox version BDE uses but it's worth a try.

You will have to use TADOTable and TADOQuery components.

Get rid of BDE as soon as you can!